# How to pass a value from a shell script to job.properties for oozie workflow

Tags: shell, oozie-workflow

I have a shell script when triggered executes certain commands and then submits an oozie workflow. My requirement is to pass an argument to the shell script, which could be used by the job.properties file of the called oozie workflow. How can I achieve that? Referring to below sample code, I want that  to be substituted in job.properties which will be used by oozie_job1.

sh test1.sh 
...
...
oozie_job1
...

Comment: it's not necessary to include a property into "job.properties", you may pass it to oozie by using command like: `oozie job -oozie <your oozie server> -config <your job properties file> -D <your property name> <your property value>`

Comment: "job.properties" is used to keep all properties together, they could be alternatively passed to oozie one by one using `-D`, which is not really neat though